# Batch requests in Google Maps Places API. - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-api-3, batch-processing

I'm looking at https://developers.google.com/coordinate/v1/batch to try and find out how to perform batch lookups of Place references.

However, I'm a bit confused with the example post on sending the batch request.

Can someone provide some example code, preferably in Objective-C explaining it a bit better

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [API clent library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).  There should be some way to easily batch requests.  I know there is for [PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/batch) and [Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch).

That is, if you're actually wanting to use the Coordinate API.  If you're trying to use the Places API, you're probably SOL because batching isn't supported as far as I can tell.